# Can't get image to show on page

Tags: html, css

Here is my header code where I want to set the background.

```
<header>
  <img src="images/MeMain.jpg" alt="Drawing of Me" class="profile-image">
  <h1 class="tag name">Hello, I’m Me.</h1>
  <p class="tag location">My home is Blank, Blank.</p>
</header>
```

Here is the associated CSS code:

```
header {
  text-align: center;
  background: url('images/portland.jpg') no-repeat top center ;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

If I code in the image to the html page it appears, but I can't get it to appear using url. I've tried moving the location of the picture, I've tried changing the url to (".../images/portland.jpg"). Nothing I've tried so far works.

Comment: Have you tried `/images/portland.jpg`?
`images/portland.jpg` will map to the current path + images/portland.jpg.
Whereas if you put a slash at the beginning, it forces the path to resolve from the root directory.

Comment: There's no way to help with this without understanding the file structure on the server.  Do you have an "images" folder on the server *with the image inside it*? How is the location of the images folder related to your HTML page? Is you CSS part of the HTML page or is it a separate linked file? If linked, where is the CSS file located on the server in relation to the "images' folder? In short... the image won't appear if the path to it is incorrect... and there's really no way to tell what the path may be to anyone other than you... everyone will just be *guessing*.

Comment: Bobby and Derek's solution fixed it. ryan, I tried both of those. All the website files are in a folder labeled Website, the images are in a 'images' folder. All the html files are in the Website folder, and all the css files are in a 'static' folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have one too many periods in the url path on your css. Also, sidenote, newer browsers don't need any quotes on the path.

Try this:

```
.header {
background: url(../images/portland.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:cover
}
```

You can even give your site a different background for a phone size screen like so:

```
@media only screen and max-width: 48em {
    .header {background: url(../images/portland-portrait.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;}
}
```

[Source - http://fritzemedia.com/](http://fritzemedia.com/css/fdn-fritze-6.1.1.css)

Answer (score -1):

the issue is that you have too many periods.

you should use

("../images/portland.jpg")

You had ...